# Font Awesome or icons on Amcharts 4 pie

Tags: javascript, amcharts

How can I add font awesome icon as label on amcharts 4 pie?

here is my codepen.io/emiks/pen/bZLeLM

PS: couldnt do it as link, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `html` attribute on the template label. There you can also use the icon placeholder `{icon}`:

```
pieSeries.labels.template.html = '<i class="fas {icon}"></i>';
```

Which will result in the following chart:

[image: chart with icons]

I forked your code pen and updated it [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zbRNmx).

**Edit:**

To change the size of the icons you can use the font-awesome size classes: `fa-2x`, `fa-3x`, ...

Comment: Thank you Very much, one more question: how can I change the size i font-size didnt work :( or did it wrong

Comment: Just use the font-awesome classes `fa-2x` or similar. I updated my answer and the code pen.